# Python requests.get() url with multiple "."

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a script to scrape a site and download mp3 files currently, it grabs all the links following into individual artist pages using `BeautifulSoup` with `Python 3.6.3` but some grabbed URLs contain more than one "." in it and when I fire

```
request.get(url, header=<random header using fake_useragent>)
```

it won't download the file, how do I correct this?

For example:

```
URL > abc.com/mp3/artist/songs/song.com.mp3 (not downloading)
URL > abc.com/mp3/artist/songs/song.mp3 (downloading)
```

code :

```
def download_mp3(url_list_file, download_dir):                                                                                                                                                                   
    with open(url_list_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as urls:                                                                                                                                                     

        for url in urls:                                                                                                                                                                                         
            ua = fake_useragent.UserAgent(verify_ssl=False)                                                                                                                                                      
            #header = {'User-Agent': str(ua.chrome.random)}                                                                                                                                                      
            artist_dir = url.split('/')[4]                                                                                                                                                                       
            song_name = url.split('/')[6].replace('\n', '')                                                                                                                                                      
            #corrected_url = ('path:url')                                                                                                                                                                        
            #print(corrected_url)                                                                                                                                                                                
            download_to = os.path.join(download_dir, artist_dir, song_name)                                                                                                                                      
            save_path = os.path.join(download_dir, artist_dir)                                                                                                                                                   
            #print(download_to)                                                                                                                                                                                  
            #print(save_path)                                                                                                                                                                                    
            print(url)                                                                                                                                                                                           
            if(os.path.isdir(save_path) == True):                                                                                                                                                                
                #print ('True')                                                                                                                                                                                  
                header = {'User-Agent': str(ua.random)}                                                                                                                                                          
                lower_download_to = str.lower(song_name)
                #To get correct file name 
                mp3_file_name = os.path.join(download_dir, artist_dir, lower_download_to.replace("www.", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))  
                mp3_file = open(mp3_file_name, "wb")                                                                                                                                                             
                temp_file = requests.get(url, headers=header)                                                                                                                                          
                mp3_file.write(temp_file.content)                                                                                                                                                                
                time.sleep(random.randint(5,10))                                                                                                                                                                 
            else:                                                                                                                                                                                                
                #print('False')  
                #To create Artist folder names 
                os.mkdir(save_path)                                                                                                                                                                              
                header = {'User-Agent': str(ua.random)}                                                                                                                                                          
                lower_download_to = str.lower(download_to)
                #To get correct file name               
                mp3_file_name = os.path.join(download_dir, artist_dir, lower_download_to.replace("www.", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))  
                mp3_file = open(mp3_file_name, "wb")                                                                                                                                                             
                temp_file = requests.get(url, headers=header)                                                                                                                                                    
                mp3_file.write(temp_file.content)                                                                                                                                                                
                time.sleep(random.randint(5,10))                                                                                                                                                                 
    urls.closed
```

Comment: `requests` doesn't care about the structure of URLs at that level of detail.  Can you post some actual, runnable code that demonstrates the problem? That will make it easier for us to help out.

Comment: Hi larsks, I have updated the question

Comment: When you say "not downloading" do you get an error?  What error?

Comment: No error code execute normaly for all the urls in the provided file  it just save the html file as mp3 :D. I noticed that bcoz file size was around 25KB

Comment: if I open a file in txt editor it contains HTML with site 404 error . this occure only if the url contain "."  at end with a domain specifier  for the file name Ex: http://acbwebsite.com/songs/artist/thesongname.com.mp3

Comment: anyone have an idea how to resolve it works in console

Answer (score 0):

got it corrected 
replaced all "." in the URL except the last one for ".mp3" with Percent-encoding using

**string.replace('.', "%2E", (string.count('.')-1))**